# Why are the contents of my JFrame not displaying correctly?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

For the sake of less code, I am taking out code that is unrelevant to the problem, such as `addActionListener();` etc.

My main class is `public class TF2_Account_Chief`

I have my main `Jframe f;` and its contents:

```
private static JFrame f = new JFrame("TF2 Account C.H.I.E.F.");
private JLabel runnableTogetherLabel = new JLabel("How many idlers would you like to run at a time?");
private static JTextField runnableTogetherInput = new JTextField();
private JButton runButton = new JButton("Run!");
private JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop!");
private JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset!");
private JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit!");
```

and I set the properties of all the contents:

```
    public void launchFrame() {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.add(runnableTogetherInput);
        f.add(runnableTogetherLabel);
        f.add(runButton);
        f.add(stopButton);
        f.add(resetButton);
        f.add(exitButton);
        f.setSize(625, 500);
        runnableTogetherInput.setSize(35, 20);
        runnableTogetherLabel.setSize(275, 25);
        runButton.setSize(60, 25);
        stopButton.setSize(65, 25);
        resetButton.setSize(70, 25);
        exitButton.setSize(60, 25);
        f.setLocation(0, 0);
        runnableTogetherInput.setLocation(285, 3);
        runnableTogetherLabel.setLocation(5, 0);
        runButton.setLocation(330, 0);
        stopButton.setLocation(395, 0);
        resetButton.setLocation(465, 0);
        exitButton.setLocation(540, 0);
    }
```

then I have my `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    TF2_Account_Chief gui = new TF2_Account_Chief();
    gui.launchFrame();
    Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(new TF2_Account_Chief());
}
```

And then I have my second `JFrame iF` which is not displaying the contents correctly:

```
private void invalidInput() {
    JFrame iF = new JFrame("Invalid Input!");
    JLabel iL = new JLabel("The input you have entered is invalid!");
    JButton iB = new JButton("Exit!");
    Container contentPane2 = iF.getContentPane();
    contentPane2.add(new TF2_Account_Chief());
    iF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    iF.pack();
    iF.setVisible(true);
    iF.add(iL);
    iF.add(iB);
    iF.setSize(500, 300);
    iL.setSize(125, 25);
    iB.setSize(60, 25);
    iF.setLocation(0, 0);
    iL.setLocation(0, 15);
    iB.setLocation(0, 45);
}
```

Now, `JFrame iF` is launched when the `invalidInput()` method is called, but you can't see that because that part of the code is unrelevant to the problem. What does matter is that the `JFrame iF` is launched.

The new frame looks like this: [image: JFrame iF]

Any ideas on why the contents are not displaying properly?

(By improperly, I mean the `JButton iB` takes up the whole frame and the frame is a light blue instead of the normal grey.)

Comment: _Any ideas on why the contents are not displaying properly_ What do you mean? Describe what is displayed, why it's wrong and how you are expecting it to be, and attach a screenshot if it's necessary

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: And thanks for fixing the screenshot.

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn how to use Layout Managers; they're your friend, not enemy...

Comment: Not related to the question, lines like `frame.pack()/frame.setVisible(true)` must come at the very end, once the programmer is done adding contents to the `JFrame` and `Jframe` by virtue of its `LayoutManager` has realized its size, with the addition of components. Not before that, it might can give obnoxious results sometimes, if not adhered to.

Comment: @nIcEcOw Thanks for the heads up! I was always taught to put those when the frame is first initialized. I will try that from now on! +1 for the info!

Comment: @nIcEcOw Yeah, I had never thought to look for that! haha! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using absolute positions without using a `null` layout, that's why you see a large button.

To see every component, you have to use

```
iF.setLayout(null);
```

**but** it's not a good practice, I'd suggest you to learn [how to use Layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and leave all the work to the layout manager

Comment: @eternay That's ok! I didn't know about it either until I went to accept the answer a minute ago! xD We all learn something for the first time at some point in time!

Answer (score 3):

The default layout of `JFrame` is  **BorderLayout**, in which there are "5" locations you can put your components to

1. CENTER
2. PAGE_START
3. PAGE_END
4. LINE_START
5. LINE_END

So, `iF.add(component)` will add the component to the `CENTER`, you can specify the location like this:

```
iF.add(component, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
//You can also put  PAGE_START, LINE_START, LINE_END, CENTER
```

Take my advice and  read more about [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), because if you refuse to learn Layout Managers, you probably go to `Absolute Positioning`( *null* layout) which is not a good way and must not be used.

Comment: If you look that BorderLayout tutorial again, it has been updated to include this information : __"Before JDK release 1.4, the preferred names for the various areas were different, ranging from points of the compass (for example, BorderLayout.NORTH for the top area) to wordier versions of the constants we use in our examples. The constants our examples use are preferred because they are standard and enable programs to adjust to languages that have different orientations."__ Still +1 for the advice :-)