# Adding multiple panels to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I know some java, but I'm new to doing any type of GUI development. Most of the things I've done have been small programs run through a terminal.

In either case, as I try to get my feet wet, I found myself stuck with the following code:

```
public class MyGui {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
      JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

      JTextArea userField = new JTextArea("User:");
      userField.setEditable(false);

      JTextArea user = new JTextArea("myuser");
      user.setEditable(true);

      leftPanel.add(userField);
      centerPanel.add(user);

      frame.getContentPane().add(leftPanel);
      frame.getContentPane().add(centerPanel);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(500, 500);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

I'd basically like a table window with fields on the left and their values on the right.  How can this be done?

My current output is just `myuser` at the center of my window.

Comment: Have you tried setting the layout of your contentPane? You could probably set it to a BorderLayout then do something like this: `frame.getContentPane().add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two panels. Just one with a GridLayout is enough:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
          JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2)); // split the panel in 1 rows and 2 cols


          JTextArea userField = new JTextArea("User:");
          userField.setEditable(false);

          JTextArea user = new JTextArea("myuser");
          user.setEditable(true);

          panel.add(userField);
          panel.add(user);

          frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setSize(500, 500);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your output will be the last panel you're adding to the container, as the default layout of `JFrame` is [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

So, `getContentPane().add(panel)`  adds the panel to the CENTER.
Also see [Why are the contents of my JFrame not displaying correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487139/why-are-the-contents-of-my-jframe-not-displaying-correctly/17487386#17487386)

The second part of your question is not specified which way to use, you can use [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) to the frame or to the main panel and add the panel to the container, again, there are other ways.

Hope you read more about [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for deep understanding.